# How to do one hot encoding in R

Tags: r, one-hot-encoding

Each opportunityID have several products
I want to have a binary column that says if an opportunity has this product or not. How to do that?

Input

```
+---+---------------+--------+----------+----------+
|   | Opportunityid | Level  | Product1 | Product2 |
+---+---------------+--------+----------+----------+
| 1 |            10 | Low    | SS       | ISP      |
| 2 |            20 | High   | ISP      | Azure    |
| 3 |            30 | Normal | Azure    | ISP      |
| 4 |            40 |        | SS       |          |
| 5 |            50 |        | ISP      |          |
+---+---------------+--------+----------+----------+
```

Expected Output(Checks over product 1 and product2)

```
+---+---------------+--------+----------+----------+--------+---------+-----------+
|   | Opportunityid | Level  | Product1 | Product2 | HasSS? | HasISP? | HasAzure? |
+---+---------------+--------+----------+----------+--------+---------+-----------+
| 1 |            10 | Low    | SS       | ISP      |      1 |       1 |         0 |
| 2 |            20 | High   | ISP      | Azure    |      0 |       1 |         1 |
| 3 |            30 | Normal | Azure    | ISP      |      0 |       1 |         1 |
| 4 |            40 |        | SS       |          |      1 |         |         0 |
| 5 |            50 |        | ISP      |          |      0 |       1 |         0 |
+---+---------------+--------+----------+----------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Code

```
library(caret)
Products <- data.frame(
  Opportunityid=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
  Level=c('Low', 'High', 'Normal', '', ''),
  Product1=c('SS', 'ISP', 'Azure', 'SS', 'ISP'),
  Product2=c('ISP', 'Azure', 'ISP', '',''))


# dummify the data
dmy <- dummyVars(" ~ .", data = Products)
trsf <- data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = Products))
trsf
```

PS: I have more than 100 products, so I want the process to be automated

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `tidyverse` to clean the data:

```
library(tidyverse)
Products <- data.frame(
  Opportunityid=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
  Level=c('Low', 'High', 'Normal', '', ''),
  Product1=c('SS', 'ISP', 'Azure', 'SS', 'ISP'),
  Product2=c('ISP', 'Azure', 'ISP', '',''), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Products %>%
   gather(key, value, Product1:Product2) %>% ## collect all Product columns
   mutate(has = ifelse(value == '', '', 1)) %>%  ## add a dummy variable
   spread(value, has, fill = 0) %>%  ## spread the values back in wider format
   select(-key, -V1) %>% ## remove empty columns and former product column
   group_by(Opportunityid, Level) %>% ## group by to collapse rows
   summarise_at(vars(-(Opportunityid:Level)), funs(max)) ## collapse rows

#   A tibble: 5 x 5
#   Groups:   Opportunityid [?]
#   Opportunityid Level  Azure ISP   SS   
#           <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1            10 Low    0     1     1    
# 2            20 High   1     1     0    
# 3            30 Normal 1     1     0    
# 4            40 ""     0     0     1    
# 5            50 ""     0     1     0
```

Comment: Thanks @thothal , Am getting this at run time Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'V1' not found

Comment: You leave out the `select` statement entirely. It was there because in your example there were empty `Product` columns. Does it help?

Comment: Do u mean I have to remove the empty variables in my dataframe, to remove this error?

Comment: Nope, just remove the `select(-key, -V1)` from my code and try again.

Answer (score 1):

data.table approach, to profit from it's fast cast and melding functions

```
Products <- data.frame(
  Opportunityid=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
  Level=c('Low', 'High', 'Normal', '', ''),
  Product1=c('SS', 'ISP', 'Azure', 'SS', 'ISP'),
  Product2=c('ISP', 'Azure', 'ISP', '',''))

library( data.table )

#create the data.table
dt <- as.data.table( Products )
#first, melt all columns containing "Pruduct"
dt.melt <- melt(dt, id.vars = 1:2, measure.vars = grep( "Product" , names( dt ) ) )
#add a value of 1
dt.melt[, value2 := ifelse( value == "", NA, 1)]
#now cast
dt.cast <- dcast( dt.melt, Opportunityid ~ value, value.var = "value2")[, c("V1", "Opportunityid") := NULL]
#replace NA with 0
dt.cast[is.na(dt.cast)] <-0
#and bind
cbind(dt, dt.cast)

#    Opportunityid  Level Product1 Product2 Azure ISP SS
# 1:            10    Low       SS      ISP     0   1  1
# 2:            20   High      ISP    Azure     1   1  0
# 3:            30 Normal    Azure      ISP     1   1  0
# 4:            40              SS              0   0  1
# 5:            50             ISP              0   1  0
```

### Benchmarks

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark( data.table = {
  #first, melt all columns containing "Pruduct"
  dt.melt <- melt(dt, id.vars = 1:2, measure.vars = grep( "Product" , names( dt ) ) )
  #add a value of 1
  dt.melt[, value2 := ifelse( value == "", NA, 1)]
  #now cast
  dt.cast <- dcast( dt.melt, Opportunityid ~ value, value.var = "value2")[, c("V1", "Opportunityid") := NULL]
  #replace NA with 0
  dt.cast[is.na(dt.cast)] <-0
  #and bind
  cbind(dt, dt.cast) },
dplyr = {
  Products %>%
    gather(key, value, Product1:Product2) %>% ## collect all Product columns
    mutate(has = ifelse(value == '', '', 1)) %>%  ## add a dummy variable
    spread(value, has, fill = 0) %>%  ## spread the values back in wider format
    select(-key, -V1) %>% ## remove empty columns and former product column
    group_by(Opportunityid, Level) %>% ## group by to collapse rows
    summarise_at(vars(-(Opportunityid:Level)), funs(max)) ## collapse rows
},
times = 100)

# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
# data.table  3.159354  3.395846  3.771977  3.598145  3.787187 13.68190   100
# dplyr      10.104990 10.451142 11.134228 10.694714 10.929098 29.83777   100
```

Comment: Can u plz explain what does this line mean `dt.cast <- dcast( dt.melt, Opportunityid ~ value, value.var = "value2")[, c("V1", "Opportunityid") := NULL]`

Comment: because using my data set am getting this error `Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(dcast(dt.melt, opportunityid ~ value, value.var = "value2"),  :
  Adding new column 'V1' then assigning NULL (deleting it).`

Comment: @sara: have you loaded the data.table library?

Comment: yeah I did load the library